# Quantum gate fSWAP acting on two-fermion states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, fermions, quantum-computer

When we have identical particles which are fermions, any exchange (swap) among 2 states introduces a minus sign. In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07112, the Eq. (7) aims to represent that operation, fSWAP, via the matrix

$$
\mathrm{fSWAP}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, if I have the state $(a\ b\ c\ d)^T = a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle$ representing 2 identical fermions, then a swap among the two of them would produce the state $(-1)·[a|00\rangle + c|01\rangle + b|10\rangle + d|11\rangle] = -(a\ c\ b\ d)^T$. Nevertheless, that matrix doesn't give you this but $(a\ c\ b\ -d)^T$. So, what am I not getting?

Comment: Fig 7 in the paper is two complicated, it should work with 2 CNOT gates.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Do you mean that instead a SWAP and a controlled-Z I could simply use 2 CNOTs? How?

Comment: With 2 CNOTs (+single-qubit gates), you can build the iSWAP gate (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209035), and the iSWAP equals the fSWAP up to Z rotations (by $\pi/2$) on both qubits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\vert0\rangle$ and $\vert1\rangle$ denotes a mode with zero or one fermions, respectively.

Then, $\vert ij\rangle$ denotes *two* modes, where $i$ denotes the number of fermions in the first mode and $j$ the number of fermions in the second mode.

So if you apply the fSWAP, what you swap is whatever is in the first and the second mode.  *But* this means you *only* exchanged two fermions if there *are* two fermions, i.e., if you were in the state $\vert11\rangle$ initially.  This is the only case in which you should get a minus sign, and this is what the fSWAP gate does.